# Showing the chosen list and input again

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am looking for way to continue my selection and stop the program when I choose 3. Here is my code:

```
Arrays.sort(a);
int x = 0;

System.out.println("Choose order: ");
System.out.println("1. Smallest to biggest.");
System.out.println("2. Biggest to smallest.");
System.out.println("3. Stop app.");
int ii = input.nextInt();

switch (ii) {
    case (1):
        for (int number : a) {
            System.out.print(" " + number);
        }
        break;
    case (2):
        for (i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < (a.length) / 2; i++, j--) {
            x = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = x;
        }
        for (int number : a) {
            System.out.print(" " + number);
        }
        break;
    case (3):
        break;
    default: {
    }
}
```

Sorry for unclear question. I know how to stop. My question is after I choose 1 command the program run and then the program show the list to choose again not stop. I added break label but it showed that only loop is labeled. So could not labeled the pintln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to continue the program until 3 pressed, then:

```
boolean app_continue = true ;
while(app_continue){
 int ii = input.nextInt();

 switch (ii) {
    case (1):
        for (int number : a) {
            System.out.print(" " + number);
        }
        break;
    case (2):
        for (i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < (a.length) / 2; i++, j--) {
            x = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = x;
        }
        for (int number : a) {
            System.out.print(" " + number);
        }
        break;
    case (3):
        app_continue = false ; // or System.exit(0) to terminate immediately;
        break;
    default: {
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: System.exit(0) ? are you sure? whynot /sbin/halt?

Comment: `break` is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us any kind of loop. If your loop is in the same method as the code you gave, you could `break` out of it (using a [labelled break](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)). Or you could set a variable that is checked in the loop condition. Or you could `return` from the method you are in.

If your loop is in another method that is calling the method with your `switch` statement in, you could `return` a value indicating that the loop should terminate.

Or, if you actually do just want to make the *whole program* immediately exit, you can call `System.exit(0);`

Comment: No. My question is how to to choose again like after I choose 1 and it is sorted and then it shows the list for me to choose again. I have add while in before the switch but the loop just run nonstop.

Answer (score 0):

use System.exit(0); write case (3) like this

```
 case (3):
     System.exit(0);
```

Comment: `System.exit` terminates the program!

Comment: in the question he said he wants to stop the program when 3 is selected